# Repeat each line into new one

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, loops

I have a test file that looks like this:

```
Hello 2
Bye 3
Tango 4
```

(the real file has 30,000 lines).

I want to get a new file that looks like this:

```
Hello
Hello
Bye
Bye
Bye
Tango
Tango
Tango
Tango
```

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
#!/bin/bash

Mywords=( $(awk '{ print $1 }' test) )
MyInteger=( $(awk '{ print $2 }' test) )
Countline=$(awk '{ print $1 }'  test | wc -l)

for ((i=0; i<$Countline ;i=i+1))
do
    for ((y=0; y<${MyInteger[$i]}  ;y=y+1))
        echo -e ${Sequences[$i]} > mynewfile
    do
    done
done
```

The `Mywords` array contains all my words (`Bye`, `Hello`, `Tango`) and the `MyInteger` array contains the number of times I want each word to be repeated.

Comment: I have improved the formatting of your code. One problem with it should be immediately clear now: your `echo` statement is in the header of a `for`-loop, instead of its body.

Comment: This can't work because the second do/done is empty.

Comment: Don't use the `echo -e` abomination; use the portable `printf` instead.

Comment: I don't know what you are actually trying to solve here, but creating a file with highly redundant information strikes me as a total waste of resources. Why not iterate when the lines are actually needed?

Comment: @Jens `make_repeats <in >bigfile; somecommand < bigfile ; rm bigfile` is not catastrophic waste of resources, especially when need run more different commands on the `bigfile`, where it start be more effective in terms of energy (cpu usage) ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use awk:

```
awk '{for (i=0; i<$2; i++) print $1}' file > output
```

Comment: lol I was writing an answer that was an exact character match to yours

Comment: @Lorkenpeist: It has happened with me also several times :P Wish you were to post earlier as I have already hit the today's rep threshold.

Comment: Thank you, very useful.
Btw, it looks like very simple :)

Comment: @JS웃: Thanks a lot for being so considerate.

Comment: @Adeel: You're welcome yes it is indeed a simple problem for awk.

Comment: @JS웃: Thanks a lot, for taking trouble and remembering.

Answer (score 1):

or perl

```
perl -ane 'chomp; print "$F[0]\n" x $F[1]' filename
```

or bash

```
while read str num; do
    for ((i=0; i<$num; i++)); do
        echo $str
    done
done < filename
```

Answer (score 1):

Another esoteric variant:

```
xargs -n2 seq -f <input.txt >out.txt
```

It is not very effective, because (in your case) will start 30k times the `seq` command, so it can be effective over the `awk` when the repetition count is bigger as 30-40k. (at least on my notebook)

Explanation:

The `xargs` will run for each 2 arguments, the `seq -f arg1 arg2` so, for your input will run

```
seq -f Hello 2
seq -f Bye 3
seg -f Tango 4
```

and for the `seq` if you provide the `format` string without the number specification (`%g`) it simply repeat the `format` N times, so the

```
seq -f hello 10
```

is equivalent to

```
yes hello | head -10
```